# Cannot find a differ supporting object in angular 5

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular-directive, ngfor, angular-components

I have used **ngfor directive in angular 5** in which I am trying to **populate rows from Firebase**..

**The HTML which I used containing ngfor directives** are as follows:

```
<!–– getting error here on below tr tag ––>
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
   <td class="left">{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{attendee.table}}</td>
   <td class="right-bill">Bill</td>
</tr>

<!–– getting error here on below tr tag ––>
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
   <td class="left">{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{attendee.table}}</td>
   <td class="right-nobill">No Bill</td>
</tr>

<!–– getting error here on below tr tag ––>
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
   <td class="left">{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{ attendee.table }}</td>
   <td class="right-itemsreceived" (click)="filled1=!filled1">
      <div class="fold" data-filled="true">
         <div class="square" [class.white]="filled1"></div>
         <span #text class="items-text">{{filled1 ?'Items Waiting': 'Items Received'}}</span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<!–– getting error here on below tr tag ––>
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
   <td class="left">{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{ attendee.table }}</td>
   <td class="right-itemswaiting" (click)="filled2=!filled2">
      <div class="fold" data-filled="true">
         <div class="square" [class.white]="!filled2"></div>
         <span #text class="items-text">{{filled2 ?'Items Received': 'Items Waiting'}}</span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<!–– getting error here on below tr tag ––>
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
   <td class="left">{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">14</td>
   <td class="table1">{{ attendee.table }}</td>
   <td class="right-unpaid">Unpaid</td>
</tr>
```

In my above HTML, I am getting the error at the 1st line `<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">` of every tr. **When I hover over that line, it states that**:

**2 ERROR 

2 ERROR CONTEXT**

At console, I am also seeing the following error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:2537)
```

**Typescript**:

The following code I have used in my typescript:

```
attendee: Attendee;
constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
const str = localStorage.getItem("attendee");
console.log(str);
if(str) {
this.attendee = JSON.parse(str);
}
}
```

The class attendee has following code:

```
export class Attendee {
  id: string;
  auction_number: string;
  dietary_restrictions: string;
  email?: string | null;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  meal_choice: string;
  table: number;
  table_name: string;
  table_type: string;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what I changes I need to make in the directives above so that I am successfully able to populate everything from the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The error explains the problem:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

`attendee` is expected to be an array or other iterable, while it is plain object that conforms to `Attendee` interface. It cannot be supplied to `ngFor` because it represents a single row.

Comment: so how can I fix this? This is my json looks like `{"auction_number":"001","email":"hello@abc.com","first_name":"Abc","last_name":"C","table":0,"id":"001"}`. It means I just need to make my json array? That's all?

Comment: Probably, yes. But there's no point in using ngFor at all. ngFor is need for multiple rows. You've got 1. You don't even use `row`. Just get rid of  `*ngFor="let row of attendee"` part.

Comment: But in future if we have multiple rows then I would want to make it scalable. let's say if I need to make that JSON array then what are the changed I need to do? I have never used ngFor before so slightly confuse. If possible can you provide an example?

Comment: I'd say this is premature scaling. ngFor has performance impact. If it isn't needed, it isn't. It would be something like `<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee"><td class="left">{{ row.first_name }}...`. You should refer to `row` and not `attendee` properties in this case.